# Getch() behavior when terminal is resized? (ncurses)

Tags: c++, ncurses

getch returns 410 when I resize terminal. Why does the getch interpret the resize as input? What's the 410? Is it a special symbol?

Code:

```
#include <curses.h>

int main() {
    initscr(); cbreak(); noecho();
    int x = getch();
    printw("%d", x);
    getch();
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

But when I use timeout I get ERR (i.e -1). Why does resizing when using the timeout lead to an error?

Code:

```
#include <curses.h>

int main() {
    initscr(); cbreak(); noecho(); timeout(10000);
    int x = getch();
    printw("%d", x);
    getch();
    endwin();

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```c
/* curses.h */
#define KEY_RESIZE  0632        /* Terminal resize event */
```

410 = 0632 (octal).

As for your second question, that doesn't happen when I test on my machine. Are you perhaps running an old version of ncurses? There have been bugs around this. https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-ncurses/2002-01/msg00003.html

Answer (score 1):

When using [`timeout`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-timeout_wtimeout) (in this case, 10 seconds), [`getch`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html#h2-RETURN-VALUE) will return `ERR` when the timeout expires.  That's in the manual pages:

> The `timeout` and `wtimeout` routines set blocking or non-blocking read for
> a  given  window.   If  *delay* is negative, blocking read is used (i.e.,
> waits indefinitely for input).  If *delay*  is  zero,  then  non-blocking
> read is used (i.e., read returns **`ERR`** if no input is waiting).  If *delay*
> is positive, then read blocks for *delay* milliseconds, and  returns  **`ERR`**
> if  there  is  still  no input.  Hence, these routines provide the same
> functionality as `nodelay`, plus the additional capability of being  able
> to block for only delay milliseconds (where delay is positive).

and

> returns **`ERR`** if the window pointer is null, or  if  its  timeout
> expires without having any data, or if the execution was interrupted by a signal (errno will be set to `EINTR`).

If you're patient (or testing slowly), you'll see a -1 returned.  It's easier if you make the program wait:

```
#include <curses.h>

int main() {
    initscr(); cbreak(); noecho(); timeout(10000);
    for (;;) {
    int x = getch();
    move(0,0);
    printw("%d", x);
    getch();
    clrtobot();
    }
    endwin();

    return 0;

}
```

That's the usual case.  If you're seeing something different, then the relevant information (version of ncurses and the platform) should be part of the question.

Comment: I assumed they were getting -1 instead of resize from the question "Why does resizing when using the timeout lead to an error?", but yes, if they're hitting the timeout then -1 is expected.