# Using ncurses from Java via JNI, resizing window does not trigger getch until key pressed

Tags: java, java-native-interface, ncurses

My goal is create text-based applications with JVM languages,
and now I am trying to use ncurses with JNI.

When I use ncurses directly from C, resizing the terminal will trigger `getch()` and return 410 (KEY_RESIZE).
But I use ncurses via JNI, `getch()` won't do anything until pressing any other keys.

- Is it a limitation of JVM?
- Any workaround for this situation?
- or shouldn't I use ncurses via JNI in the first place?

Here is the full reproducible code:

```java
public class Main {
    public static native void init();
    public static native int  getch();
    public static native void printw(String string);
    public static native void endwin();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.loadLibrary("jcurses");
        init();
        for (int key; (key = getch()) != 'q';)
            printw("%d\n".formatted(key));
        endwin();
    }
}
```

```c
#include <ncurses.h>
#include "Main.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Main_init(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz) {
    initscr();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    noecho();
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Main_getch(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz) {
    return (long) getch();
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Main_printw(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jstring javaString) {
    const char *nativeString = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, javaString, 0);
    printw("%s", nativeString);
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, javaString, nativeString);
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Main_endwin(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz) {
    endwin();
}
```

```
all:
    javac -h . Main.java
    gcc -I"$$JAVA_HOME/include" -I"$$JAVA_HOME/include/linux" jcurses.c -shared -o libjcurses.so -lncurses
run:
    java -Djava.library.path=. Main
```

For comparison, here is the pure C code to do the same thing.
Resizing the window will shows up 410 immediately but cannot do the same with JNI.

```c
#include <ncurses.h>

int main() {
    initscr();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    noecho();
    for (int key; (key = getch()) != 'q';)
        printw("%d\n", key);
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Tested on devices below:

- x86 ubuntu22.04, ssh from Windows 7 git bash
- arm64 ubuntu22.04, native gnome terminal

Comment: AFAIK, `getch()` does capture window resizing event, and I could actually do it with pure C. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64177492/getch-behavior-when-terminal-is-resized-ncurses

Comment: So your question is why doesn't `getch()` return the expected value of 410 on window resize? Suggest you say so, in your question.

Comment: Added to the question. thanks for improving the question

Answer (score 0):

I found that the issue is that the JVM "consumes" the SIGWINCH signal,
so that ncurses cannot detect the changes of the size of the window.

Therefore a possible solution is using the `sun.misc.Signal` class to catch the signal and do the rendering stuff,
but this is an absolutely bad idea due to its deprecation.

```java
// WARNING! this package is deprecated!
import sun.misc.Signal;

Signal.handle(new Signal("WINCH"), signal -> {
    // re-render our contents
});
```

(This answer should not be accepted)